# Can I use eye bolt to mount kid swing?

Tags: hardware, play-structures, backyard

I am planning to mount swing (max 100 lbs) using eye bolt like this

[image]

Is there disadvantage vs. the swing hanger sold by playset manufacturer?

Comment: I used eye bolts through a beam for 2 swing's over 30 years ago. Big washers on top and nylock nuts so they would not back off.  Now my grand kids use the swings and they still work fine.

Comment: Looks good -- But keep the vendor-supplied hangers. If a kid falls off the swing and breaks his neck, you're gonna want to remove your eyebolts and install the original hangers before suing the swingset manufacturer.